# click link from alternative element with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, click, jquery-traversing

While there is a lot of good resources on traversing the DOM with jQuery I am not having any luck on my example.

On my site www.smithgrey.co.uk I have a series of thumbnail galleries all which have a 'section title' div in front of them.

What I want to achieve is when you click on the 'section-title' div the first `<a href>` link of the thumbnail to the right will clicked.

There are multiple instances of the `class="section-title"` – Unfortunately I am not able to add any ID or Classes as this is generated dynamically and have been asked to keep it as is if possible.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="content-grid">
    <div class="section-title">
      <span class="section-title-type">Title of the first thumbnail gallery</span>
    </div>

    <div class="index-article">
      <a href="#" class="fancybox">
        <img src="thumbnail-1">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="section-title">
      <span class="section-title-type">Title of the second thumbnail gallery</span>
    </div>

    <div class="index-article">
      <a href="#" class="fancybox">
        <img src="thumbnail-2">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="index-article">
      <a href="#" class="fancybox">
        <img src="thumbnail-3">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="index-article">
      <a href="#" class="fancybox">
        <img src="thumbnail-4">
      </a>
    </div>   
  </div>
</body>
```

And here is my jQuery so far but it does not yield the result I would imagine because it will click the link no matter if I click the first or second `<div class="section-title">`.

```
$('div.section-title').click( function(){
       $(this).parent().next($('div.index-article')).children('a.fancybox').click();
     });
```

**Solution:**

With the help of the other commentors I managed to figure out how to make it work as I expected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.section-title').click( function(){
    $(this).next('.index-article').find('a.fancybox:first').click();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you have setup your jQuery correct with the appropriate ready event/etc.  This is how I'd do it.  Please note I've added a click event to the hyperlink to simulate the click in the jsfiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/s9mds/

```
$('div.section-title').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next('div').find('a:eq(0)').click(); 
});​
```

Comment: Hey I gave you suggestion a go but no luck but I began to fiddle with the .next() and I got it to work – so thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('div.section-title').click( function(){
     $(this).closest($('div.index-article').find('a.fancybox').click();
   });
});
```

Comment: hey thank you for the input but it's not giving me any result and after looking at the closet() on jQuery's docs I can see it only travels UP in the DOM and I assume I would need to go down – not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hey @jhonarymos sorry if I made it look/sound that way. The idea is that when you click on the first instance of the div with class="section-title" then it will open the link which contains <img src="thumbnail-1">. if you on the other hand press the second instance of class="section-title-type" then you will open the link which is wrapped around <img src="thumbnail-2"> – does that make any sense (mind you this is not my day job so explaining what I barely can wrap my head around is tricky but you help is much appreciated :)

Comment: okk So you want to say if i click "section-title" than show thumbnail-1 or if i click "section-title-type" than show thumbnail-2? am i right

Comment: Hey @jhonraymos I just solved it please see the updated post it should explain it best :) but thank you for the inputs.

Comment: @SofusGraae Gud but i don't know that `closest()` goes only upwards.If it goes downward than my answer is solution of your question..